# How to put Text View above the Image and at the bottom of Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I have tried almost everything from `Gravity` to `alignParentTop` and `layout_above` but nothing seems to be working here.

I have an `ImageView` and a `TextView` I am using `ViewPager` to display different images and their respective `text`.

The Problem is that, its displaying `Text` at the top and image after it.

I want it to display `Image` and beneath it display `TextView`.

This is what i am getting after adding following `xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"

        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/image_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="Image Text"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Kindly guide me how to put `Text` after the `Image`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `android:layout_below` attribute should solve your problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/image_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image_view"
        android:text="Image Text"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Stackoverflow at its best !! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this it may help you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300sp"
    android:src="@drawable/wallpaper"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:id="@+id/imageView" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This is test"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:layout_below="@+id/image_view"` in your `TextView`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_height="200dp"

            />
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/image_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/image_view"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:text="Image Text"
            />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it helps you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can define this structure tow way, first one define Textview  property android:layout_below as ImageView id like bellow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/image_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="Image Text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And other one use LineLinearLayout and define orientation vertical like following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/image_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Image Text" />

</LinearLayout>
```